# Git log: how to get all commits' stat of Github repo

Tags: git, github, git-log

For example in bootstrap
When using

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an%x2C%ae%x2C%ai%x2C" >> filename
```

I can get 16000+ commits

I want to get addition and deletion in a commit, so I use

```
git log --stat --pretty=format:"%an%x2C%ae%x2C%ai%x2C" >> filename
```

but I only get 6000+ commits

How to get all 16000+ commits stat? Thank you.

Comment: Both commands should be able to get the same commits if `HEAD` refers to the same commit.

Comment: As @ElpieKay noted both commands traverse the same *set* of commits. But `--stat` only shows *non-merge* stats; stats for merge commits are generally useless. You can force stats (which won't be very useful) with `--cc` or `-c`, or one-stat-per-parent with `-m`, which will effectively *split* merges so that you get more stats than there are commits.

Comment: @torek thanks. Again I learned.